# Tomcat , Intellij and DCEVM configuration

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, dcevm

I had configured DCEVM on intellij, but I think the way I did it is wrong as when I made some change in the java file and ctrl + shift + f9, the tomcat is getting restarted. Can someone please tell me the correct way to configure it.

Comment: I have tried various variations of this idea over the years, and none of them live up to their promises, including the commercial ones. You're probably spending more time trying to get this to work than you'd have spent restarting your app whenever your interfaces change. If you use spring-boot then you can start/stop your app very rapidly (usually).

Comment: I've used jrebel, and it works fantastically. It is expensive though.

Comment: Is your setting like this?  `<Context reloadable="true">`

Answer (score 0):

In intellij tomcat debug configuration, add the following parameters to your JVM arguments like this :

```
-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:/home/depellegrin/Applications/hotswap-agent.jar=autoHotswap=true
```

change **/home/depellegrin/Application/** by your DCEVM-light-...-installer.jar path.
For more information take a look at this [blog](http://javacolors.blogspot.com/2015/09/the-great-alternative-to-jrebel.html)